# Is it valid to assign ID to TR or TD in table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Title itself is self explanatory.

Just as a curiosity I want to know if its possible and most importantly valid to assign ID to `TR` or `TD` in Table?

Like :

```
<td class = "xyz" id = "abc"></td>
```

or

```
<tr class = "xyz" id = "abc">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

I googled it but couldn't find relevant answer so I thought I could ask here.

Thanks !

Comment: Yes. Of course it is

Comment: Of course it is...nothing wrong with it at all if you need to target that **specific** `td` / `tr`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes.

From [the HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes)

> The following attributes are common to and may be specified on **all HTML elements** (even those not defined in this specification):
>
> …
>
> - id
>
> …

Answer (score 2):

That is completely valid. You can give any HTML-element a class or ID.

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet, and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with the specific id.

Source: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is valid to have class and/or id on those elements. You can apply them to all HTML elements. For more info see

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

As you can see class and id are Global attributes

> Global attributes are attributes common to all HTML elements; they can
>   be used on all elements, though the attributes may have no effect on
>   some elements.

Answer (score 1):

The id is used to refer the html control in css file or javascript. You need to ensure that no two id are matching even though it is not prohibited but will lead to enexpected result.

in css:

```
<style>
  #myid{
    color:red;
  }
</style>
```

in JQuery:

```
<script>
    alert($("#myid").name;
</script>
```

update: fixed error of using class selector in place of id selector.

Comment: This helps but it doesn't directly answer the question ;)

Comment: you are using the class selector "." Since we're working with id's here you should use the ID selector "#".

Answer (score 1):

You can target your `<td>` using `class` or `id` just like any other elements via CSS. It is perfectly valid based on W3C standards.